# Laravel returns 404 when route has multiple parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've upgraded from 5.8 to 6 to 7 following the documentation. Now I have a problem where the verification email route returns 404.

I've had a read around and seen a few errors where people have not followed the docs. I have read and implemented the below from the upgrade guide.

> "The route path for verifying emails has changed from
>   /email/verify/{id} to /email/verify/{id}/{hash}."

But there seems to some underlying routing problem. With a little more investigation I've discovered that this works:

```
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{other}', function($id, $other){
    dd([$id,$other]);
});
```

and this does not (the route auth uses but with a closure to test):

```
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function($id, $hash){
    dd([$id,$hash]);
});
```

the rest of the web.php routes file is empty.

It would seem using the word **hash** causes the 404 rather than displaying the array.

When using:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

the **route:list** command does display the expected route.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Simply add `_token` field to data of your ajax request.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not making an ajax request. When I go back to the original routes the URL does contain a token. I think this is a matter of working out why the request doesn't work when the param is called 'hash'.

Comment: I don't think there should be anything to do really. I've tested your code in a fresh Laravel 7 app and it's working with either `hash` or `other` as the route parameter. What's the exact error message you're getting? Is it because the *route* couldn't be found or the *controller* or method?

Comment: Thanks, Dan, I feel like this is a problem with the upgrading from 5.8 to 7 (through 6). There's nothing in the log when I try and hit this page and I just get a 404 page.